# Approximation of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}$

Tags: functions, approximation

How do you prove this statement?

> If $x\gg R$ then
>   $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}\cong 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2$$

I have no ideas even how to start.

Comment: See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this can be seen by a [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) around $0$. Note that $x\gg R$ "means" $\frac{R}{x} \approx 0$: so you would need to make this quantity appear, first.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}} &= \frac{x}{x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2}}
= \frac{x}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2 + o\left(\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2\right)\right) \\
&= 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2 + o\left(\frac{R^2}{x^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
using the fact that $(1+u)^\alpha = 1+\alpha u + o(u)$ when $u\to0$ (for any fixed $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 0):

Compare these two functions at $x=\infty$. If their quotient $f/g$ tends to $1$, it means $f\sim g$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{R}{x}\right)^2}=
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}}{\frac{2x^2-R^2}{2x^2}}=
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\cdot 2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}(2x^2-R^2)}=
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+R^2/x^2}(2-R^2/x^2)}=1$$

Comment: This is slightly problematic as written -- an equivalent is just a first-order approximation, so what is above only provides the 1 -- **not** the $1-\frac{R^2}{2x^2}$. To see why, observe that the exact same argument gives a limit of $1$ for $\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}}{1-7652973\frac{R}{x}}$...

Comment: For your argument to be correct, you would need to consider instead the limit of $$ \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}-1}{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{R^2}{x^2}}$$ and show it is 1.

Comment: @ClementC. it highly depends on how do you understand $\cong$ symbol. Note that your function $1-7652973R/x$ approximates $x/\sqrt{x^2+R^2}$ at infinity very well! :) Nevertheless, you are right, I might have misunderstood this question.